# jQuery Getting: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/app/home

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, popup, syntax-error

I'm getting Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/app/home
at

```
  $(document).click(function () {
    var url = document.URL.split("/");
    if (url[url.length - 1] == "home") {
        $("#upperNavIcon").attr("src", "");
        $("#upperNavLink").attr("href", "");
    } else if (url[url.length - 1] == "contact") {
        $("#upperNavIcon").attr("src", "IMGS/home_icon.png");
        $("#upperNavLink").attr("href", "#/app/home");
    } else if (url[url.length - 1] == "news") {
        $("#upperNavIcon").attr("src", "IMGS/home_icon.png");
        $("#upperNavLink").attr("href", "#/app/home");
    } else if (url[url.length - 1] == "selectedNew") {
        $("#upperNavIcon").attr("src", "IMGS/share_icon.png");
        $("#upperNavLink").attr("href", "#small-dialog");
    }
});
```

**Please note that I don't get that error when I remove this function which is used to show my popup from Magnific-Popup-master**

```
$('#upperNavLink').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    fixedContentPos: false,
    fixedBgPos: true,
    overflowY: 'auto',
    closeBtnInside: true,
    preloader: false,
    midClick: true,
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
});
```

I'm putting both functions in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //here
});
```

function

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to check !

jQuery use **escape** for href !

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11773

olso check documentation of magnificPopup. I'm not sure if preloader: false, is ok.

The following function takes care of escaping these characters and places a "#" at the beginning of the string:

var myhref = "/app/home";

function jq( myhref ) {
      return "#" + myhref.value;
}